# Laravel beforeFilter in controller doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to apply a filter to the login and register pages, so already logged in users will be redirected from them to the index page. Here is the route:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
```

Here are beforeFilters in the UserController:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('guest', ['on' => 'getLogin']);
    $this->beforeFilter('guest', ['on' => 'getRegister']);
}
```

Here is the getLogin action:

```
public function getLogin()
{
    return View::make('users/login');
}
```

And the filter itself (filters.php):

```
Route::filter('guest', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

However, when I'm already logged in and trying to access login or register pages I don't get a redirect to '/'. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'on'` is actually for specifying a HTTP verb. Try this instead:

```
$this->beforeFilter('guest', ['only' => ['getLogin', 'getRegister']]);
```